# Retornar mensagem caso nenhum checkbox seja selecionado

Tags: java, android

Como fazer o tratamento neste código para que retorne mensagem ao usuário selecionar pelo menos um checkbox caso ele não selecionar nenhum?

```
    public void verificaCheckBox(){

    Listcheck.clear();

    if (cbPapel.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbPapel.getText().toString());

    if (cbPlastico.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbPlastico.getText().toString());

    if (cbMetal.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbMetal.getText().toString());

    if (cbVidro.isChecked())
        Listcheck.add(cbVidro.getText().toString());


        cbSelecionado = (Listcheck.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outra forma seria testar o tamanho da sua lista `Listcheck`(supondo que e sua lista seja uma `Collection`) após passar por seus `if` de adição.

```
public void verificaCheckBox(){

  Listcheck.clear();

  if (cbPapel.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbPapel.getText().toString());

  if (cbPlastico.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbPlastico.getText().toString());

  if (cbMetal.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbMetal.getText().toString());

  if (cbVidro.isChecked())
    Listcheck.add(cbVidro.getText().toString());

  if(Listcheck.size() > 0){
    cbSelecionado = (Listcheck.toString());
  }else{
    //nenhum checkbox selecionado
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cbPapel.isChecked())
   Listcheck.add(cbPapel.getText().toString());

if (cbPlastico.isChecked())
   Listcheck.add(cbPlastico.getText().toString());

if (cbMetal.isChecked())
   Listcheck.add(cbMetal.getText().toString());

if (cbVidro.isChecked())
   Listcheck.add(cbVidro.getText().toString());

if (Listcheck.isEmpty()){
   //Msg que não foi selecionado nenhum
}
```

Comment: O tratamento está dando certo. Mas quando seleciono mais de um, só chega a primeira opção ao enviar para o BD.

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição na minha resposta, volte como estava seu código então, e no final de tudo, inclua um novo if que vai verifcar se o seu array de selecionados está vázio